# How do I install Windscribe VPN if their repository is forbidden in the country?

Tags: apt, package-management

Whenever I try `sudo apt-get update` I get this error:

```
W: Failed to fetch https://repo.windscribe.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not connect to repo.windscribe.com:443 (10.10.34.35), connection timed out
```

The [windscribe.com](https://windscribe.com) VPN is forbidden in my country. Is there any other way to install winscribe-cli package manually? I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS x86_64.

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.

Comment: I don't think even after installing Windscribe you'll be able to connect to the VPN. Have you tried the [browser extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/windscribe-free-proxy-and/hnmpcagpplmpfojmgmnngilcnanddlhb)?

Comment: If installing is forbidden in your country USING it will be impossible. Your government will actively block access to the VPN.

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution

1. visit: https://windscribe.com/guides/linux
   with your mobile (use an android vpn)
2. in the website click on "Give Me Binaries" button
3. download the Windscribe for your linux distro
4. copy the .deb file to linux and install the downloaded .deb file
5. open terminal and write this code:
   windscribe login
6. enter your user name and password
7. write this code to connect:
   windscribe connect
8. enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the mind-blowingly smart answer you'd expect and it obviously doesn't work for downloads via the terminal, but you can use a vpn in the form of a browser extension ([Windscribe has one](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/windscribe/) too), then [download the Windscribe GUI deb file](https://windscribe.com/guides/linux) from your browser, use the dpkg command in the page to install it and use it afterward.

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps:

1. Download the ".deb" package from [Windscribe Debian package page](https://windscribe.com/changelog/linux_deb) by clicking on your intended version number.

   - As a note, you can download this resource from another device that has access to download it with the help of a VPN or other tools and then move it to your Ubuntu system.
2. Then, on your Ubuntu system, run the following command in the directory that you saved the ".deb" package:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i YOUR_DOWNLOADED_PACKAGE_NAME.deb
   ```

Now you can use the Windscribe CLI tool with `windscribe` commands.